# c# Google Cloud Upload Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, google-cloud-storage

I try to upload my files from my ASP.NET  webform.

1-) Shell I use UploadObject or UploadObjectAsync what is the different I will have users and they will upload some files. Which is better for my project ?.

2-) `Client.UploadObject(bucket,fileName,)`
The third param is content type. When I upload file manuel from Storage a picture the content type is image/png.How can I give the content type as param I have file extension in my hand as .jpg or .png.

3-)If I have the same file name in the path it should not be upload and throw exception.

Example in AZURE  I use this :

```
AccessCondition.GenerateIfNoneMatchCondition("*")
```

4-) What is CancellationToken should I use the default I cant find any documention about this..

5-)Could you please explain IUploadProgress I cant find any documention about this.

6-)I will upload in the second sub folder like (Uploading to video folder) but in which param should I give the path

Mat / Document / Video